# :contains incorrectly selecting child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Currently I'm trying to select a link element with the jQuery `:contains` selector. This works when the contents of the link is just text. but it seems that when the element contains other HTML elements the :contains selector selects a child element instead. Example

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><b> two</b> this not bold <b>This</b> is a bold Link</a>
```

from that html, I'm trying to select the link using this selector
jQuery:

```
var selector = "a:contains('<b> two</b> this not bold <b>This</b> is a bold Link')";

var returnObj = $(selector);
```

Instead of getting one returned object (the link), jQuery returns three objects:

1. the first bold element
2. the text `this is not bold`
3. the second bold element

the problem isn't the single quotes within the `contains()`, as I've tried with and without them.

This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. In reality, I'm dynamically creating selectors based off of a link object a user clicks. I then store that selector in a database for use later (for my app to display content related to that link). Since I can get the contents of the link, I figured I'd just use `a:contents()` if the link doesn't have an `id`.

based off of these pages, I seem to have my syntax right:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_to_Get_Anything_You_Want_2
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Thoughts on how to get the link object returned? Thanks!

hope this isn't too stupid a question, I'm new to JS and jQuery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parent

Comment: contains does'nt really work on your HTML, it's meant for text only.

Comment: `:contains()` looks at text content only, not HTML. However, it *is* bizarre that `a:contains(...)` would return `b` elements. I would have expected jQuery to return an empty set.

Comment: Heh, that *is* bizarre. http://jsfiddle.net/eDw7U/

Comment: Ah Hah! if I strip out the html and have the selector: "a:contains('two this not bold This is a bold Link')", it works as expected. Any chance anyone knows how to create a selector with the behavior that I'd expect above?

Comment: @user1893161: Yes, you certainly don't want HTML markup in your selector, unless that's what the text content actually contains. But the result is really strange when including the HTML markup.

Comment: @BoltClock, it seems like it is not finding the `b` inside the link, but it is actually created a new in-memory node .. see http://jsfiddle.net/TA8rX/ this might constitute a jQuery bug ..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Guessed as much... I posted my own answer to expand on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, `:contains()` is meant to select by text content only, not inner HTML.

If you must match the `a` element based on that text, strip out the `<b>` tags:

```
var selector = "a:contains(' two this not bold This is a bold Link')";
```

Otherwise, see if you can simplify this selection by using a contextual selector (e.g. select based on its surrounding elements, parents, siblings, etc), or assign it a class and select by that class instead.

On a side note, I'd consider this yet another jQuery bug (could be a parsing error in [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com)). In your situation, `:contains()` is not supposed to return or create any elements; it's supposed to return no matches simply because the selector doesn't match your `a` element. I suspect what it's doing instead is treating the `<b></b>` tags as new elements, and creating them on the fly along with your `a` element, which is wrong because the tags are inside the argument string and meant to be taken literally...

Comment: after reading a bit on jQuery, it is not really a bug .. the http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 states "***If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has <tag ... > somewhere within the string).***" and later on "***But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.***"

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Hmmm, then wouldn't it produce just the `b` elements and discard the `a` instead of trying to match it? Or is it interpreting the `:contains()` argument as its own string and evaluating that on its own?

Comment: It only finds tags when creating elements.. `$('text<a>link</a>other text');` will only create a `<a>link</a>`

Comment: Why is it finding `a` when it's not creating an `<a>`?

Comment: @BoltClock, it **does** discard the `a` element. it just creates new a new `b` element. no matching at all occurs.. the whole *selector* is treated as new html since it contains tags. They get extracted and created as elements.

Comment: The answer [is here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.2/src/core.js#L105-L109) in the main jQuery function, which uses the captured result of [this regex](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.2/src/core.js#L45). This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDw7U/1/) shows the full and captured result.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: OK, I iterated `returnObj` and it produces tag names B, undefined and B. Is that undefined tag name the text node between the two B elements, all the text nodes combined, or something else?

Comment: @BoltClock: Use `.nodeName` and you'll get `#text`.

Comment: @IHateLazy: Ah ha, knew it.

Comment: it seems to be discarding all text up to first tag and all text after last tag. in between are created as text nodes.. kind of a tag-trim  `$('pretext<b>bold</b>betweentext<a>anchor</a>posttext').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});`

Comment: thanks guys! I understand this way more now. I'm stripping the HTML elements, and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your selector text does not match the actual text in your html.
The selector includes the `this not bold` which is not present in the html.

Most importantly the `:contains` works with the text only.. so you should check for

```
$("a:contains('two this not bold This is a bold Link')");
```

It is a very inefficient way though, and you should better add a class to the elements you want to target and use that for targeting..

Comment: "which is not present in the html" That was probably an error in the question which I've corrected. It's still not supposed to match with the selector that the OP has, though.

Comment: thanks! I'm aware that this particular selector is not the most efficient route. This is a last resort, and Unfortunately I'm selecting elements that aren't in _my_ html  -- so I don't have the option to add IDs or Classes that I can select on.